# Understanding finding object in an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

**My Attempt**

Hi, so we can do something like

```
var myArray = [{'id':'73','foo':'bar'},{'id':'45','foo':'ye'}];
    function getById(id, myArray) {
    return myArray.filter(function(obj) {
      if(obj.id == id) {
        return obj 
      }
    })
    }

    get_my_obj = getById(45, myArray);
    console.log(get_my_obj);
```

To filter our object. However after some testing I realized that I wasn't getting the result I needed, I noticed that if I add `[0]` as such

```
return myArray.filter(function(obj) {
      if(obj.id == id) {
        return obj 
      }
    })[0]
```

**Problem**

This works perfectly. Why do I need `[0]`?

Comment: `filter` returns are array of matching elements. [read the docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Array.prototype.filter` *filters* an array; it removes the elements from the array which don't fit your predicate. The result is *an array*, presumably shorter than the one you started with.

What you're looking for is [`Array.prototype.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find), which returns the *first* match only.

Comment: [0] points to {'id':'73','foo':'bar'}, so I'm wondering why my code works when I look for the id of 45 which is in spot [1]

Comment: The indices of the filtered array do not correspond to the original indices. Only the values are returned, in a new array, which is freshly continuously indexed starting at `0`.

Comment: I see. so whats happening when we don't put [0], behind the scenes? its still logging something [Object]

Comment: It's logging *the array*.

Comment: But why do you say I use find instead? This seems pretty good other than it wont return things with multiple of the same ids

Comment: As far as I understand your question, `.find` does exactly what you need: it returns the first match, it returns only one match, and it stops searching when it finds the match. `.filter` on the other hand searches the entire array and returns an array, even though you apparently only want one result.

Answer (score 2):

Array filter gives back an array. This array consist of every row of the original array for which your filter function return true.

Even if the array has only one entry, it's still an array

before:

```
[0]{'id':'73','foo':'bar'}
[1]{'id':'45','foo':'ye'}
```

after:

```
[0]{'id':'45','foo':'ye'}
```

Think of a different example

```
[0]{'id':'73','foo':'bar'}
[1]{'id':'45','foo':'ye'}
[2]{'id':'32','foo':'ye'}
[3]{'id':'33','foo':'ye'}
[4]{'id':'33','foo':'baz'}
```

Now the function shoult filter any row which has the value 'ye' for foo

```
[0]{'id':'45','foo':'ye'}
[1]{'id':'32','foo':'ye'}
[2]{'id':'33','foo':'ye'}
```

You see. In both cases the returned value is an array of matching objects. It would be awkward if we would return only the single matching object if we got only one match (`{'id':'45','foo':'ye'}`).

At first the filter method has to make the decision if to return the array or the object. Then the receiver of the returned value has to check if the value is an array or an object. This would be rather strange.

---

> filter() calls a provided callback function once for each element in
>   an array, and constructs a **new array** of all the values for which
>   callback returns a value that coerces to true. callback is invoked
>   only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not
>   invoked for indexes which have been deleted or which have never been
>   assigned values. Array elements which do not pass the callback test
>   are simply skipped, and are not included in the new array.

Bold by me
From: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: Ok let me say what I am thinking. Suppose we dont have [0]. then we look for our id say 73. We go into our array and filter it. First we start at myArray[0] if  {'id':'73','foo':'bar'}'s id (73) is the same as the one we are looking for (which it is) we return this whole object. Great! So why [0]..

Comment: You think, how you would have programmed it. But you should take what you get. It's more convenient to return always an array than to return a single object, if the array would consist of only this object.

Answer (score 1):

In short [`Array#filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array with the item where the callback returns `true`.

If you expect only one item, you better use [`Array#some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) and set an index.

```js
function getById(id, myArray) {
    var index = -1;
    myArray.some(function (obj, i) {
        if (obj.id == id) {
            index = i;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return myArray[index];
}

var myArray = [{ 'id': '73', 'foo': 'bar' }, { 'id': '45', 'foo': 'ye' }],
    get_my_obj = getById(45, myArray);

console.log(get_my_obj);
```

Comment: Are you poorly reimplementing `.findIndex()` using `.some` as an iterator...?! Odd choice of methods...

Comment: @deceze, what is a better solution without es6?

Comment: 1) Returning the index and then using the index to access the element seems odd for starters. 2) `.find` is obviously the best method, and if you have to polyfill something anyway, polyfill `.find`.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your result was this:

```
[{'id':'73','foo':'bar'}]
```

This is an array with just one object inside. But, using the index (`[0]`), you get the first element inside the array (which has only one). In that case, the object:

```
{'id':'73','foo':'bar'}
```

Comment: But if I try to look up the id of 45, it works as well, and this is at [1] of the array.

Comment: Not the returned array.

Comment: I'm confused. What im asking is why am I getting my desired result if I look up the id of 45. As you say [0] points to the object with id 73

Comment: No. I'm not explaining how to get what you want: the other guys are. I'm just explaining what does that [0] do (and that was, in fact, your question!). Keep in mind that I'm talking about the returned array, that has only one element.